# Git installer cannot run, windows 11. Has weird file name

Tags: git, installation, filenames

I'm trying to install git (2.42.0) 64-bit version of Git for Windows from https://git-scm.com/download/win.
After downloading the installer, it has a strange name and I can't run it:
[image]

file name: 255edd25-cca0-4294-909c-b46bced63e3f

If I double click the file, Windows asks me to select an app to open this file. That's not normal. It's just supposed to start the installer.

Comment: None of the binaries behind the download links on that page have file names like that. You probably did something wrong when you downloaded it. Try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure this is the file you downloaded from Git's website, you can
rename the file to *Git-2.24.0.2-64-bit.exe* (you might need to change version numbers) and then run it.
[image]

The file has all the data for the installer, it just needed to be ran as an executable. Renaming it like this makes that possible. Hope this helps anyone else who had the same issue.

Note: Only do this if you're sure this is the file you downloaded from git's download portal. If you don't trust the file, delete it and try again.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this advice generalizes poorly. If you have a corrupted download, there are myriad other things which could be wrong, including but not limited to that you could end up running malicious code this way.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to install git v2.42.0 on a new laptop. Opening a new browser with admin privileges and then downloading it solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am a programmer from China. Because of our special network, I encountered the same problem as you when downloading the latest version of the 64bit installer from the official website, which was also solved by renaming. Change the name of that strange file to "Git-2.42.0.2-64-bit.exe" and double-click it to run it. Another solution is to restart the VPN. This is how I solved it.